# wordpress localization extending

Tags: localization

I am using a .mo file in my language directory of wp-content. But It doesn't trnslate some words and all the numerical contents of the site. How can I add these to the .mo file? Or is there any other way to translate those contents?

Comment: Do you mean to translate you actuall content meaning: pages, posts etc - of the theme language meaning the: "tags:", "COmments form" etc ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dont use the strings inside the theme or plugin the function for localisation, then it is not possible to add this to the mo/po file. You must change the source of the theme or plugin.

But used the theme or plugin the functions, than parse the source via plugin or desktop tools to add the strings to the mo/po files.
use:

- plugin [Localization](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/)
- Desktop [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/)